# Google script loop running only 1 loop (google sheets)

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a strange behavior on my google script for a google sheet from a previous IT guy.
The for loop run for 1 iteration instead of 800+

I got an array of rows "invoiceRows" that i can see on the Logger.log
I can log the invoiceRow.length (800+ rows), the invoiceRow[0] and the invoiceRow[invoiceRow.length-1]. Everything is correct.
Then I do a very simple for loop `for(var i=0 ; i<invoiceRow.length ; i++){`

Inside the loop, i=0 => correct

Outside the loop, i=1 => correct, if there were only 1 item in the array

There is no break nor continue (well, there is one for security purpose, but the log is not displayed).
I have a try catch with a log on e, but there is no exception.
There were a while loop before, which didn't work neither.

What id does is pretty straight forward : get rows of invoices rows, for each: populate a template sheet, create a pdf, then set the pdf url at the end of the line

```
// BOUCLE DE TRAITEMENT DES DONNEES
    Logger.log('BOUCLE - avant ; nb d\'itérations: '+invoiceRows.length);
    for(var i=0 ; i<invoiceRows.length ; i++){
      var currentRow = startRow+i;
      Logger.log(' - boucle item #'+i+", row #"+currentRow+": "+invoiceRows[i]);
      if(invoiceRows[i][0]==""){
        Logger.log('   id vide => break');
        break;
      } 
      Logger.log('   id #'+i+": "+invoiceRows[i][0]);
      
      if (true) { // une raison de ne pas traiter la ligne ? Déjà faite ?

        templateSheet.getRange("F10").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Account Billing Address"]].replace(/<br>/g, "\n"));
        templateSheet.getRange("A17").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Invoice: Name"]].split(" ")[0]);
        templateSheet.getRange("A18").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Invoice: Name"]]);
        templateSheet.getRange("G18").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Date"]]);
        templateSheet.getRange("G14").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Account Siret"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("G15").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Account TVA"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("B20").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Account RRF"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("A22").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Title"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("D22").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Princing - Per Unit"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("F22").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Princing - Nb of units"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("A24").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Princing - Modify label"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("G24").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Princing - Modify value"]]); 
        //templateSheet.getRange("F38").setValue((invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Princing - TVA"]] || 0) / 100); 
        templateSheet.getRange("F38").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Princing - TVA"]]+"%"); 
        templateSheet.getRange("B42").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Account Payment Terms"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("B45").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Account Mode de paiement"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("F9").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Account Commercial Name"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("D23").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Princing - Flat Fee"]]); 
        templateSheet.getRange("B21").setValue(invoiceRows[0][headerObj["Campaign Scope"]]); 
        Logger.log('template updated');
        
        var sheetToPrint = templateSheet.copyTo(dummySpreadsheet);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        Logger.log('template copied into dummySpreadsheet');
        
        var totalFromTable = invoicesSheet.getRange(currentRow, parseInt(headerObj["Total HT"], 10)  + 1).getValue();
        Logger.log('total HT: '+totalFromTable);
        var totalTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("G36").getValue();
        Logger.log('total HT calculé dans le template: '+totalTemplate);
        // contrôle si montant ht est cohérent entre ligne et template => poursuivre
        if (
          parseFloat(templateSheet.getRange("G36").getValue()).toFixed(2) == parseFloat(totalFromTable).toFixed(2) 
          && totalFromTable
        ) { 
          Logger.log("contrôle cohérent entre template et ligne");
          var dummySheets = dummySpreadsheet.getSheets();
          for (var b = 0; b < dummySheets.length; b++) {
            if (dummySheets[b].getName() != sheetToPrint.getName()) {
              dummySpreadsheet.deleteSheet(dummySheets[b])
            }
          }
          var blob = dummySpreadsheet.getAs("application/pdf");
          blob.setName(invoiceRows[0][1] + '.pdf');
          
          var uid = null;
          var printId = null;
      
          if (!folder) {
            var folder =  DriveApp.getFolderById("fakegooglefolderid");
          }
          var file = folder.createFile(blob);
          Logger.log("file: "+JSON.stringify(file, null, 2));
          Logger.log('headerObj["Drive Link"]: '+JSON.stringify(headerObj["Drive Link"], null, 2));
          invoicesSheet.getRange(currentRow, parseInt(headerObj["Drive Link"], 10) + 1).setValue(file.getUrl())
      
        
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        } // fin du contrôle cohérent total ttc
        
        // cas où il n'y a pas de total ht
        else if(!totalFromTable) {
          invoicesSheet.getRange(currentRow, parseInt(headerObj["Error"], 10) + 1).setValue("Empty total value")
        }
        else if (parseFloat(templateSheet.getRange("G36").getValue()).toFixed(2) != parseFloat(totalFromTable).toFixed(2)) {
          invoicesSheet.getRange(currentRow, parseInt(headerObj["Error"], 10) + 1).setValue("Values not matching")
        }
        else {
          invoicesSheet.getRange(currentRow, parseInt(headerObj["Error"], 10) + 1).setValue("Unknown")
        }
    } 

    else{ // si ligne pas traitée

    }

    invoiceRows = invoicesSheet.getRange(currentRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getDisplayValues();
      Logger.log('   fin de boucle i='+i);
    }
    Logger.log('BOUCLE - après ; items traités: '+i);
```

The loop just don't run again as it should, until it reach the 800+ `for(var i=0 ; i<invoiceRow.length ; i++){`

The script was working last month, as it does for years. I really don't understand this behavior.
Is there a know bug with google sheet script ?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: You give a lot of code but no indication of where it is failing.

Comment: invoiceRows and startRow undefined

Comment: Did the data change? Are you still targeting the same range of cells / same sheet? If you are, is there data in your target range, or did everything shift a couple of rows down? Is your loop ending with the `break`? As Cooper mentioned, `invoiceRows` and `startRow` are undefined. Are you defining them somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Post the whole function

Comment: In fact the problem is quite simple.
I have an array of 800+ rows (log confirms it), and a loop that only iterate one time (log confirms it) instead of 800+.
The rest of function before/after is irrelevant.
Yeah, there is some code, because if there is not, people will ask some code to check break or continue (which is fine).
In the end, i just made the same function from scratch with pieces of code that interest me, and it works this way.
Why the code above don't ? I don't know. At this point, I don't care. But thanks for your attention everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, i just made another function from scratch, with pieces of code that interest me : get the array, loop on it x times, treat data.

And it works this way.

Why the code above don't ? I really don't understand.

Thanks for your attention everyone.